# Sonata page - test is decorated page in Symfony route controller

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

I try setup template in the controller - compatible with sonata page.

I have a working application (Symfony 4), I install sonata-page, admin, block .. everything work nice. 
And now try use page decorator to existing routes- it returns a full page with a header. If I can get information in Symfony route controller- the page is decorated - I can return the only content response without a head.